# Cookies set on another server could not be retrieved using CURL

Tags: php, curl, cookies

I'm not sure if what I want to do is possible but here's the case.

Cookies are set on server A (first name, last name, etc).

I have a script on server A which gets the cookies, saves it into the db for future use and then finally displays it. Let's say the script is getCookies.php

Here's the code:

```
include 'dbconnect.php';

$sessid = $_GET['sid'];

$un = $_COOKIE['un'];
$ul = $_COOKIE['ul'];
$up = $_COOKIE['up'];
$ue = $_COOKIE['ue'];
$idn = $_COOKIE['idn'];

if(!empty($un) || !empty($ul) || !empty($up) || !empty($ue) || !empty($idn)){ // Save log to Database
    $savedate = date('Y-m-d G:i');
    $q = "INSERT INTO cookiedb (sid, un, ul, up, ue, idn, savedate) VALUES ('$sessid', '$un', '$ul', '$up', '$ue', '$idn', '$savedate')";
    $rs = mysqli_query($con,$q);
}

echo "$un, $ul, $up, $ue, $idn";
```

The code above works if I directly access the script from the browser. However, if I access on another server (server B) using CURL, the cookies doesn't seem to work. It's not being read and saved in the db. I'm getting a blank response. I even used some codes like this suggestion I found here on stackoverflow:

```
$url = "http://serverA.co.za/getCookie.php";
$ch = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
// get headers too with this line
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
$result = curl_exec($ch);
// get cookie
// multi-cookie variant contributed by @Combuster in comments
preg_match_all('/^Set-Cookie:\s*([^;]*)/mi', $result, $matches);
$cookies = array();
foreach($matches[1] as $item) {
    parse_str($item, $cookie);
    $cookies = array_merge($cookies, $cookie);
}
var_dump($matches);
```

...but this code does not work. Do you have any idea how I can get the value for those cookies? If CURL could not be used here, are there any other ways? Thank you.

Comment: A cookie is stored in the browser. If you command your server to visit the page with CURL it indeed won't have the cookie. Why do you want to use cookies for this case? Why would storing the data in a database not work?

Comment: Oh okay. Well I guess that explains why I'm not getting the cookies. It does not save to the db since I've put a condition that if there are no values for the user info ($un, $ln etc.) it won't save. In this case, cookies were not read so there were no values in the $un, $ln etc thus it did not save in the db